# Matlab, font rendering problem

Tags: 16.04, fonts, matlab

I have an issue with Matlab. The thing is that Matlab fails to render fonts properly. When I click on or move the Matlab window, it fixes, The same problem occurred when I used Ubuntu Gnome, Ubuntu Mate, Kubuntu, Mint Mate (all 16.04.1 or 16.04) I know it is there also for Unity (on the colleague's desktop). The problem didnt occur if I used Fedora based system, both on Gnome and KDE desktops. I tried different versions of Matlab (namely, 2014b, 2015b, 2016a), the problem is there.
We didn't get any reliable response from Mathworks forums, so maybe someone of you faced the same problem or have a clue how it can be solved?

[image]

Comment: Same problem here: http://askubuntu.com/q/816874/308164 might be a bug.

Comment: Please, specify your GPU and hardware. I can reproduce the problem only with the package `xserver-xorg-video-intel`.

Comment: Hi, sorry for being so late.I switched the os and forgot that I had a post here. Please, the needed info.
`
Machine:   Device: laptop System: Acer product: Aspire V3-372 v: V1.01
           
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i5-6200U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB
Graphics:  Card: Intel HD Graphics 520 bus-ID: 00:02.0
`