# How to Have Clear Matlab's texture with xserver-xorg-video-intel?

Tags: intel-graphics, fonts, matlab

Origin of the problem: `xserver-xorg-video-intel` is buggy but the differential solution is `modesetting` (option 1 [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/816631/25388)) does not allow to fix brightness control (F5/F6). 
File `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf/20-intel.conf` for the current condition

```
# Joakim, https://askubuntu.com/q/816631/25388
Section "Device"
   Identifier "Intel Graphics"
   Driver "intel"
   Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
   Option "TearFree" "true"
   Option "DRI" "3"
   Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
EndSection
```

Fig. 1-4 Outputs in Matlab where you see cluttering of texture

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Differential solution: `sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-intel`, and Ubuntu starts to use `modesetting` package instead. Output: clear texture in Matlab.

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Linux kernel: 4.7
Matlab: 2016a
Related: [Matlab, font rendering problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809582/matlab-font-rendering-problem)
Matlab service request: 02135568

Comment: Look like a bug to me. [This question](http://askubuntu.com/q/809582/308164) reports a similar problem. I have Matlab 2015, and do not have that problem. Although I have 14.04. Did you tried a different Matlab version?

Comment: @luchonacho I am testing the Intel package in different hardwares. I think the bug is in the intel package with the hardware. - - My previous hardware uses NVidia GPU so it does not have it. - - No, I have not tested different Matlab versions about the case.